# Hibernate: Could not deploy application packaged persistence provider

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, persistence, wildfly

I'm trying to upgrade Hibernate from version **4.2.21.Final** to version **5.2.5.Final** but I have been having some troubles since last week. So far, I haven't been able to find anything about this problem in my searches...
Whenever I modify **pom.xml** and set the new version for Hibernate, I get the following exception when deploying the project:

```
10:08:44,397 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) WFLYDS0004: Found MaisAcoes.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called MaisAcoes.war.dodeploy
10:08:44,466 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYSRV0027: Starting deployment of "MaisAcoes.war" (runtime-name: "MaisAcoes.war")
10:08:47,251 WARN  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYSRV0059: Class Path entry activation.jar in /C:/Users/vinic/Desktop/SEATI/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/standalone/deployments/MaisAcoes.war/WEB-INF/lib/mail-1.4.1.jar  does not point to a valid jar for a Class-Path reference.
10:08:49,493 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."MaisAcoes.war".FIRST_MODULE_USE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."MaisAcoes.war".FIRST_MODULE_USE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment "MaisAcoes.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:154)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJPA0019: Could not deploy application packaged persistence provider 'org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider'
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderHandler.deploy(PersistenceProviderHandler.java:79)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.deploy(PersistenceBeginInstallProcessor.java:49)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:147)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider
    at java.lang.Class.asSubclass(Class.java:3404)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceProviderHandler.deploy(PersistenceProviderHandler.java:72)
    ... 7 more

10:08:49,505 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "MaisAcoes.war")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"MaisAcoes.war\".FIRST_MODULE_USE" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"MaisAcoes.war\".FIRST_MODULE_USE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment \"MaisAcoes.war\"
    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYJPA0019: Could not deploy application packaged persistence provider 'org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider'
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider"},
    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"MaisAcoes.war\".FIRST_MODULE_USE"],
    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined
}
10:08:49,658 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "MaisAcoes.war" (runtime-name : "MaisAcoes.war")
10:08:49,658 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0183: Service status report
WFLYCTL0186:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.deployment.unit."MaisAcoes.war".FIRST_MODULE_USE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."MaisAcoes.war".FIRST_MODULE_USE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase FIRST_MODULE_USE of deployment "MaisAcoes.war"
```

What am I missing? Here's my **pom.xml*:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>MaisAcoes</groupId>
    <artifactId>MaisAcoes</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- ****** HIBERNATE****** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ****** ****** -->

        <!-- ****** JAVA SERVER FACES ****** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ****** ****** -->


        <!-- ****** PRIME FACES ****** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
            <version>5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ****** ****** -->

        <!-- ****** PRIME FACES ALL THEMES****** -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
            <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ****** ****** -->

        <!-- Apache Commons: Email -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Java EE 7 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Quartz (serviço "cron" para o projeto) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I'm using **WildFly 10.1**.

Answer (score -1):

WildFly 10.1.0.Final should default to Hibernate 5.0.10.Final.

Generally speaking you can't include dependencies in your deployment and expect a Java EE server to use the dependencies. The container has a lot of integration with the specific versions that are bundled. It's generally best to not worry about the dependencies in the container and develop towards the Java EE API's.

That said with Hibernate you may be able to [replace it](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/JPA+Reference+Guide?_sscc=t#JPAReferenceGuide-ReplacingthecurrentHibernate5.xjarswithanewerversion).